# What’s the best way to log messages from Cadence workflows and activities?

Tags: cadence-workflow

In my workflows and activities, I’d like to log some messages for debugging purposes.

I saw the `cadence.GetLogger(ctx).Info()` function, but don’t know where to find the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Go Client:**

You can use the following in the workflow code:

```
cadence.GetLogger(ctx).Info(...)
```

In the activity code, you should use the following:

```
cadence.GetActivityLogger(ctx).Info(...)
```

By default, the logger will write to console, which may be sufficient for development purposes. However, you should log to a file if you need the logs in production, too. Here is how to setup your cadence worker to do it:

```
workerOptions := cadence.WorkerOptions{
 Logger: myLogger, 
} 
worker := cadence.NewWorker(service, domain, taskList, workerOptions)
```

The Cadence client uses [zap](https://github.com/uber-go/zap) as the logging framework. You can create the zap logger and specify the log file path per your needs. Check out the [zap documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap?tab=doc) to learn more about configuring the logs.

**Java Client**

The Java client uses `slf4j` for logging. You can get the logger instance by calling `Workflow.getLogger()` and configure it in `logback.xml` as usual.